# jquery mobile dialog navigation does not work

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

this has been puzzling me all morning.

I have a dialog in my Jquery mobile page. All is working fine but only AFTER I F5 the page.

I now have the following page

```
<div data-role="page" id="pictures">

        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="#" id="logoutbutton"  data-role="button" data-icon="home">Log Uit</a>
            <h1>Foto's</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="grid_outer" id="grid_outer_pictures" style="width: 275px;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                <div  class="grid_inner" id="grid_inner_pictures">
                    <h2 class="h2_header">Mijn Foto's</h2>

                    <?php

                    if ($nrofuserpictures < 3) {
                        echo "
                    <input value='Voeg Toe' data-icon='add' data-theme='b' type='button' id='addpicturebutton'>
                    ";
                    }
                    ?>

                    <?php
                    include 'php/show_m_userpictures.php';
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /content -->

        <?php
        include 'homefooter.php';
        ?>

        <!-- /footer -->
    </div><!-- /page -->

    <div data-role="dialog" id="confirmbox">
        <div data-role="header" data-icon="false">
            <h1>Bevestig</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->

        <div data-role="content">
            <h3 id="confirmMsg">Confirmation Message</h3>

            <br>

            <center>
                <a href="#" class="btnConfirmYes" data-role="button" data-icon="check" data-mini="true" data-inline="true">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ja&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="#" class="btnConfirmNo" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="delete" data-mini="true" data-inline="true">Nee</a>
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The show_m_userpictures.php script generates a div with the picture and a delete button like so:

```
<div class='picture'><img id='userpicture' width='170' height='139.4' src='../users/annet/pictures/example.png' pictureid='30' class='unapproved' /></div><div style='min-width: 150px; max-width: 150px;'><input value='Verwijder' data-icon='delete' data-theme='b' type='button' id='deletepicturebutton' pictureid='30'></div>
```

I have the following javascript code in a separate js file.

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#pictures', function() {
alert('pageshow pictures ');

$("[id=deletepicturebutton]").on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var pictureid = $(this).attr('pictureid');

    alert('deletepicturebutton clicked pictureid ' + pictureid);

    showConfirm("Weet je zeker dat je deze foto wilt verwijderen ?", function() {

        $.ajax({
            async : false,
            url : "../php/process_delete_picture.php?pictureid=" + pictureid,
            success : function(data) {
                if (data != "") {
                    // in case of error
                    alert(data);
                } else {
                    alert("Foto verwijderd !");
                    window.location.href = "pictures.php";

                }
            }
        });
    });

});
```

});

And the showConfirm function.

```
// confirm dialog
function showConfirm(msg, callback) {
$("#confirmMsg").text(msg);
$("#confirmbox .btnConfirmYes").on("click.confirmbox", function() {
    $("#confirmbox").dialog("close");
    callback();
});

$("#confirmbox .btnConfirmNo").off("click.confirmbox", function(r) {
});

//$.mobile.changePage("#confirmbox");
$.mobile.changePage('#confirmbox', 'pop', false, true);
```

}

I don't understand why the dialog is not shown the first time I enter the page and click on one of the delete buttons?? I am doing a pageshow event, tried it with pagebeforeshow and I even added the javascript to the bottom of the page.

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE**

I tried to navigate to an external page like this

```
$.mobile.changePage('confirmbox.php', 'pop', false, true);
```

And that works! but this is not what I want because then I can't use a callback properly. So somehow the page on first load is not aware of the dialog box (???).

Comment: You tried beforepageshown or `pagebeforeshow`?

Comment: pagebeforeshow, sorry, was typo in post, I will correct it

Comment: Try to call the dialog without changing the options of the changepage.

Comment: I already tried that, without any options, the changepage only works after a 'hard' refresh of the page.

Comment: Do you use document ready anywhere in your code?

Comment: @Gajotres no I don't ....

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to find out what exactly is happening in this case. If you could post a working example which reproduces the case it would help a lot.

I've modified some parts of your code. Note that in your implementation, multiple calls of the showConfirm method seems to attach the click event on the dialog's button more than one times. The result is that the callback is called multiple times.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>StackOveflow Case</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).on('click', '#pictures #deletepicturebutton', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var pictureid = $(this).attr('pictureid');
                alert('deletepicturebutton clicked pictureid ' + pictureid);
                showConfirm("Weet je zeker dat je deze foto wilt verwijderen ?", function () {
                    /*
                    $.ajax({
                        async: false,
                        url: "../php/process_delete_picture.php?pictureid=" + pictureid,
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data != "") {
                                // in case of error
                                alert(data);
                            } else {
                                alert("Foto verwijderd !");
                                window.location.href = "pictures.php";

                            }
                        }
                    });
                    */
                    alert('in callback');
                });
            });

            function showConfirm(msg, callback) {
                $("#confirmMsg").text(msg);

                $("#confirmbox .btnConfirmYes").unbind("click").click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $("#confirmbox").dialog("close");
                    callback();
                });

                $.mobile.changePage('#confirmbox', {
                    transition: "pop",
                    reverse: false,
                    changeHash: true
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="pictures">
            <div data-role="header">
                <a href="#" id="logoutbutton" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Log Uit</a>
                 <h1>Foto's</h1>

            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content">
                <div class="grid_outer" id="grid_outer_pictures" style="width: 275px;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
                    <div class="grid_inner" id="grid_inner_pictures">
                         <h2 class="h2_header">Mijn Foto's</h2>

                        <div class='picture'>
                            <img id='userpicture' width='170' height='139.4' src='../users/annet/pictures/example.png' pictureid='30' class='unapproved' />
                        </div>
                        <div style='min-width: 150px; max-width: 150px;'>
                            <input value='Verwijder' data-icon='delete' data-theme='b' type='button' id='deletepicturebutton' pictureid='30'>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /page -->
        <div data-role="dialog" id="confirmbox">
            <div data-role="header" data-icon="false">
                 <h1>Bevestig</h1>

            </div>
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="content">
                 <h3 id="confirmMsg">Confirmation Message</h3>

                <br>
                <center>
                    <a href="#" class="btnConfirmYes" data-role="button" data-icon="check" data-mini="true" data-inline="true">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ja&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="#" class="btnConfirmNo" data-role="button" data-rel="back" data-icon="delete" data-mini="true" data-inline="true">Nee</a>
                </center>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: you mean the "[id=deletepicturebutton]" tag? this fires only once for the appropriate button, not many times. This should be regular Jquery logic, I use it a lot on non-mobile webaaps.  Your example does not work..... I need to F5 the page for the event to fire. I am almost sure is has something to with multiple buttons generated and multiple events, but I don't see how.

Comment: I mean the showConfirm method. If you press the confirm button more than once then the click event is attached multiple times and the callback is called multiple times. The code I posted seems to work as is. That's why I asked you if it is possible to provide an example which reproduces the issue. Without being able to reproduce the issue it's hard to guess the root cause.